# Failed to do integration test in Clickhouse by running with runner script

Tags: clickhouse

I tried to run integration tests via docker from this [README.md](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/blob/master/tests/integration/README.md#running-with-runner-script), but ran into some problems.

Here's my development environment:

```
[boblee@Wsl[19:50:36]server]$ sudo docker version
Client:
 Version:      17.06.1-ce-rc1
 EulerVersion: 17.06.0.10
 API version:  1.30
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   7a547fb
 Built:        Fri Mar 23 05:39:01 2018
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.06.1-ce-rc1
 EulerVersion: 17.06.0.10
 API version:  1.30 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   7a547fb
 Built:        Fri Mar 23 05:38:32 2018
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

I use `docker pull yandex/clickhouse-integration-tests-runner` and fetch the recommended image from Yandex.

```
[boblee@Wsl[19:52:10]server]$ sudo docker images
REPOSITORY                                   TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
yandex/clickhouse-integration-tests-runner   latest              811ba8d0c7f3        5 days ago          1.49GB
```

> The only requirement is  and docker pull yandex/clickhouse-integration-tests-runner

So, my question is: what does `fresh configured docker` mean?

Can I assume that the pulled docker image already has all third-party dependencies for integration test?

Then:

I went to the `$CLICKHOUSE_HOME/tests/integration` and run following command, also from the [README.md](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/blob/master/tests/integration/README.md#running-with-runner-script)

```
sudo ./runner --binary /home/boblee/ClickHouse/build_20.13.1.1_debug/programs/clickhouse  --bridge-binary /home/boblee/ClickHouse/build_20.13.1.1_debug/programs/clickhouse-odbc-bridge --base-configs-dir /home/boblee/ClickHouse/build_20.13.1.1_debug/programs/server/ 'test_odbc_interaction -ss'
```

Part of the errors:

```
Start tests
======================================================================================================== test session starts =========================================================================================================platform linux -- Python 3.6.9, pytest-6.2.2, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /ClickHouse/tests/integration, configfile: pytest.ini
plugins: timeout-1.4.2
timeout: 300.0s
timeout method: signal
timeout func_only: False
collecting ... ENV                  DOCKER_KERBEROS_KDC_TAG latest
ENV         CLICKHOUSE_TESTS_SERVER_BIN_PATH /clickhouse
ENV                                 HOSTNAME DESKTOP-MB3AOEA
ENV                                    SHLVL 0
ENV                              PYTEST_OPTS test_odbc_interaction -ss
ENV                                   OLDPWD /
ENV                                     HOME /root
ENV              DOCKER_MYSQL_PHP_CLIENT_TAG latest
ENV         CLICKHOUSE_TESTS_CLIENT_BIN_PATH /clickhouse
ENV               DOCKER_MYSQL_JS_CLIENT_TAG latest
ENV                                     TERM xterm
ENV                                     PATH /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
ENV                           DOCKER_CHANNEL stable
ENV        DOCKER_POSTGRESQL_JAVA_CLIENT_TAG latest
ENV           DOCKER_MYSQL_GOLANG_CLIENT_TAG latest
ENV                           DOCKER_VERSION 5:19.03.13~3-0~ubuntu-bionic
ENV                                      PWD /ClickHouse/tests/integration
ENV             DOCKER_MYSQL_JAVA_CLIENT_TAG latest
ENV       CLICKHOUSE_ODBC_BRIDGE_BINARY_PATH /clickhouse-odbc-bridge
ENV         CLICKHOUSE_TESTS_BASE_CONFIG_DIR /clickhouse-config
ENV                                       TZ Europe/Moscow
CLUSTER INIT base_config_dir:/clickhouse-config
collected 10 items

test_odbc_interaction/test.py Cluster start called. is_up=False, destroy_dirs=True
Trying to kill unstopped containers...
ERROR:
        Can't find a suitable configuration file in this directory or any
        parent. Are you in the right directory?

        Supported filenames: docker-compose.yml, docker-compose.yaml

ERROR:
        Can't find a suitable configuration file in this directory or any
        parent. Are you in the right directory?

        Supported filenames: docker-compose.yml, docker-compose.yaml

Unstopped containers killed
('Removing instances dir %s', '/ClickHouse/tests/integration/test_odbc_interaction/_instances')
Setup directory for instance: node1 destroy_dirs: True
Copy common default production configuration from /clickhouse-config
Create directory for configuration generated in this helper
Create directory for common tests configuration
Copy common configuration from helpers
Generate and write macros file
Copy custom test config files ['/ClickHouse/tests/integration/test_odbc_interaction/configs/openssl.xml', '/ClickHouse/tests/integration/test_odbc_interaction/configs/odbc_logging.xml', '/ClickHouse/tests/integration/test_odbc_interaction/configs/enable_dictionaries.xml', '/ClickHouse/tests/integration/test_odbc_interaction/configs/dictionaries/sqlite3_odbc_hashed_dictionary.xml', '/ClickHouse/tests/integration/test_odbc_interaction/configs/dictionaries/sqlite3_odbc_cached_dictionary.xml', '/ClickHouse/tests/integration/test_odbc_interaction/configs/dictionaries/postgres_odbc_hashed_dictionary.xml'] to /ClickHouse/tests/integration/test_odbc_interaction/_instances/node1/configs/config.d
Setup database dir /ClickHouse/tests/integration/test_odbc_interaction/_instances/node1/database
Setup logs dir /ClickHouse/tests/integration/test_odbc_interaction/_instances/node1/logs
Env {'LLVM_PROFILE_FILE': '/var/lib/clickhouse/server_%h_%p_%m.profraw'} stored in /ClickHouse/tests/integration/test_odbc_interaction/_instances/node1/env_file
Entrypoint cmd: bash -c "clickhouse server --config-file=/etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml --log-file=/var/log/clickhouse-server/clickhouse-server.log --errorlog-file=/var/log/clickhouse-server/clickhouse-server.err.log --daemon; tail -f /dev/null"
Setup MySQL
Stderr:
b'Creating network "roottestodbcinteraction_default" with the default driver\nPulling mysql1 (mysql:5.7)...\nGet https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)\n'

Stdout:
b''

Failed to start cluster:
Command ['docker-compose', '--project-directory', '/ClickHouse/tests/integration/test_odbc_interaction', '--project-name', 'roottestodbcinteraction', '--file', '/compose/docker_compose_mysql.yml', 'up', '-d', '--force-recreate'] return non-zero code 1: b'Creating network "roottestodbcinteraction_default" with the default driver\nPulling mysql1 (mysql:5.7)...\nGet https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)\n'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/ClickHouse/tests/integration/helpers/cluster.py", line 655, in start
    subprocess_check_call(self.base_mysql_cmd + common_opts)
  File "/ClickHouse/tests/integration/helpers/cluster.py", line 60, in subprocess_check_call
    run_and_check(args)
  File "/ClickHouse/tests/integration/helpers/cluster.py", line 54, in run_and_check
    raise Exception('Command {} return non-zero code {}: {}'.format(args, res.returncode, res.stderr))
Exception: Command ['docker-compose', '--project-directory', '/ClickHouse/tests/integration/test_odbc_interaction', '--project-name', 'roottestodbcinteraction', '--file', '/compose/docker_compose_mysql.yml', 'up', '-d', '--force-recreate'] return non-zero code 1: b'Creating network "roottestodbcinteraction_default" with the default driver\nPulling mysql1 (mysql:5.7)...\nGet https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)\n'
None
Command ['docker-compose', '--project-directory', '/ClickHouse/tests/integration/test_odbc_interaction', '--project-name', 'roottestodbcinteraction', '--file', '/compose/docker_compose_mysql.yml', 'up', '-d', '--force-recreate'] return non-zero code 1: b'Creating network "roottestodbcinteraction_default" with the default driver\nPulling mysql1 (mysql:5.7)...\nGet https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)\n'
EEEEEEEEEE

=============================================================================================================== ERRORS ===============================================================================================================__________________________________________________________________________________________ ERROR at setup of test_mysql_simple_select_works __________________________________________________________________________________________

    @pytest.fixture(scope="module")
    def started_cluster():
        try:
            cluster.start()
            sqlite_db = node1.odbc_drivers["SQLite3"]["Database"]

            print("sqlite data received")
            node1.exec_in_container(
                ["bash", "-c", "echo 'CREATE TABLE t1(x INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC, y, z);' | sqlite3 {}".format(sqlite_db)],
                privileged=True, user='root')
            node1.exec_in_container(
                ["bash", "-c", "echo 'CREATE TABLE t2(X INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC, Y, Z);' | sqlite3 {}".format(sqlite_db)],
                privileged=True, user='root')
            node1.exec_in_container(
                ["bash", "-c", "echo 'CREATE TABLE t3(X INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC, Y, Z);' | sqlite3 {}".format(sqlite_db)],
                privileged=True, user='root')
            node1.exec_in_container(
                ["bash", "-c", "echo 'CREATE TABLE t4(X INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC, Y, Z);' | sqlite3 {}".format(sqlite_db)],
                privileged=True, user='root')
            print("sqlite tables created")
            mysql_conn = get_mysql_conn()
            print("mysql connection received")
            ## create mysql db and table
            create_mysql_db(mysql_conn, 'clickhouse')
            print("mysql database created")

            postgres_conn = get_postgres_conn()
            print("postgres connection received")

            create_postgres_db(postgres_conn, 'clickhouse')
            print("postgres db created")

            cursor = postgres_conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute(
                "create table if not exists clickhouse.test_table (column1 int primary key, column2 varchar(40) not null)")

            yield cluster

        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)
>           raise ex

test_odbc_interaction/test.py:98:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
```

Currently， It seems that the docker cannot run correctly because the `docker-compose.yaml` is not found

> ERROR:
> Can't find a suitable configuration file in this directory or any
> parent. Are you in the right directory?
> Supported filenames: docker-compose.yml, docker-compose.yaml

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem and came back here to share my solution.

This problem is probably caused by the network environment. If you have a proxy configured for Docker, It may help to change the proxy or simply pull the images manually (You can find the required image from `$ClickHouse/docker/test/integration/runner/compose/xxx.yml)`.